# Xcode: forget about old repositories

Tags: xcode, svn, repository, xcode7

Xcode 7.2 gives me warnings every time I build:

> ```
> MyProject Project    2 issues        /!\
>     oldSvnProject
>       /Users/grumdrig/src/oldSvnProject is missing from working copy
>     anotherOldProject
>       /Users/grumdrig/src/anotherOldProject is missing from working copy
> ```

I haven't used svn in years. These projects have nothing to do with Xcode. I've tried deleting the reference to an old subversion repo in `Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Repositories`. I've deleted every file inside my project directory that so much as mentions svn, which is these two:

```
MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/grumdrig.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/MyProject.xcscmblueprint
```

after quitting Xcode. But they always come back.

*Listen, and understand! That [Xcode] is out there! It can't be bargained with. It can't be reasoned with. It doesn't feel pity, or remorse, or fear. And it absolutely will not stop, ever, until you are
[frustrated].*

Comment: A wild guess: is there a chance that these paths and svn-related stuff is still in your build script?

Comment: It is mentioned in the project directory only in the files that I listed above, that I've deleted repeated (and alway come back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHA! I believe I have it. There was an old, ossified `.svn` directory in the directory above my project directory. Deleting it caused the warnings to vanish in an instant!